# Report HTML + CSS + Print - Chrome bug

Tags: html, css, printing, report, css-tables

I'm trying to make a report in HTML + CSS.
My template contains a header, a content and a footer. I want to repeat the headers and footers in all pages, as basics reports.

My CSS look like that:

**Header:**

```
@media print {
 div.report-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000034;
  }
}
```

**Footer:**

```
@media print {
  div.report-header {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000034;
  }
 }
```

The possible bug is that on Firefox, the report works fine, repeating header and footer in all pages, but in Chrome, the header is present only on the first page and the footer only in last page.

I tried many tutorials, including using Tables:

```
@media print {
  thead { display: table-header-group; width: 100%; background: red;}
  tfoot { display: table-footer-group; width: 100%; background: green;}
}
```

But the result is the same, Firefox working fine while Chrome does not work.
Please, what can I do to do this simple report? Is there any plugin to do something like that?

I'm using Chrome Version 24.0.1312.70.

Comment: I'm a year too late.  I'm having similar problems printing DIVs in Chrome using @media print CSS.  It's still an issue in Chrome 32.  I wonder whether it has something to do with the way Chrome renders its Print Preview screen - I think it might rely on its Chrome PDF Viewer plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, this only works in Firefox, Opera and IE.